# FileReader() - Problems with closure and passing arguments

Tags: javascript, closures, filereader

I have a few issues with the [`FileReader.onload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader) Event:

What is the reason that I get different results between the following two code snippets? As soon as I pass the `object` instance, instead of the explicit `this.attachmentIndex` value, I get a different result.

### 1)

```
fileReader.onload = (function (file, obj) {
                    return function (evt) {
                        obj.attachmentIndex // 1
                    };
                })(f, this);
```

### 2)

```
        fileReader.onload = (function (file, index) {
            return function (evt) {
                index // 0
            };
        })(f, this.attachmentIndex);
```

## Closure - FileReader.onload()

One additional problem that I am facing is that I can't seem to pass more than one argument to my `FileReader.onload()` event handler.

```
        fileReader.onload = (function (file, one, two) {
            return function (evt) {
                one // 1
                two // undefined
            };
        })(f, 1, 2);
```

Below you can find whole object.I had to do some ugly stuff to achieve what I wanted. I really hope there is a better way to achieve the same result.

```
function Note() {
    this.attachmentOutput = [];
    this.attachmentIndex = 0;
    this.debugging = false;
    this.currentWorkingObject = new NoteObject(helperFn.createGuid());
    this.addAttachement = function(files) { 
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader(),

            fileReader.onload = (function (file, obj) {
                return function (evt) {
                    var base64File = evt.target.result;
                    obj["note"].addDataToAttachementObj(obj["index"], { data: base64File })
                };
            })(f, { note: this, index: this.attachmentIndex});

            // Async => reading file
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);

            this.attachmentIndex++
        }

        var html = app.outputTemplate(this.currentWorkingObject.attachements);
        $('.upload-output').html(html);
    };

};
```

Trigger for the function:

```
$(".upload-drop-zone").on('drop', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        app.myCurrentNote.addAttachement(files);
    });
```

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: I want `0` as a result for the `index` value in the closure - in the end I got it but just with this ugly workaround. If I don't pass the argument explicitly, then I get `1` and I don't know why. Would be so much easier, if I could just pass `this` to the closure and from there access `attachmentIndex`.

Comment: Not certain interpret Question correctly ? What is purpose of `f` within `for` loop at `var i = 0, f; ` ? Is `i` defined at `f = files[i]` ? Tried `for (var i = 0; i < files.length;  i++) {` ?

Comment: It saves me the additional hassle to retrieve the file object. I also need `i` in the code I just skipped this code snippet because I thought it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> I want 0 as a result for the index value in the closure - in the end I
>   got it but just with this ugly workaround. If I don't pass the
>   argument explicitly, then I get 1 and I don't know why.

`FileReader` is asynchronous . `this.attachmentIndex` appear to be incremented to `1` at

```
    // Async => reading file
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);

    this.attachmentIndex++ // <- `this.attachmentIndex` incremented to `1` here
```

possibly before `FileReader.onload` event called.

Comment: That's what I thought but why is it that `this` + accessing the index in the closure gives me a different result then passing it explicitly as `this.attachmentIndex`

Comment: @KingJulien Not certain following _"why is it that this + accessing the index in the closure gives me a different result then passing it explicitly as `this.attachmentIndex`"_ correctly ? Tried to increment `this.attachmentIndex` from within `FileReader.onload` event ? e.g.; before `FileReader.onload` define `that = this;` , within `FileReader.onload` , following `.addDataToAttachementObj` , `++that.attachmentIndex` ?